# How to use direct "tetgen.h" and the functions to generate meshes without using "tetgen.exe"?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, delaunay, tetgen

Our team is working on a project in which we are using tetgen file for generation of 3D meshes and right now we are using you `tetgen.exe` file to get results.

Now what we want to do is to use direct `tetgen.h` and the functions to generate meshes without using `tetgen.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

As an example of how to integrate and call tetgen's API from another program, you can take a look at my GEOGRAM library [1], in particular the following file:

```
src/lib/geogram/delaunay/delaunay_tetgen.cpp.
```

There are a couple of gotchas, concerning the way constraints are represented, and the way memory should be released to avoid a memory leak. The file includes some comments.

[1] http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can uncomment:

```
#define TETLIBRARY
```

in tetgen.h and then you can use tetgen like any C++ library. For more information:
[refer](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/1.5/doc/manual/manual007.html).